# Using python help to get help on MatchObject

Tags: python

I am trying to use the help() function in the Python interactive shell to get help on MatchObject. I have already imported re, and whether I try help(MatchObject), help(re.MatchObject), help(matchobject), or any other variation on these above choices I get a NameError.

I realize that I can look up help about MatchObject and its methods on the Internet, however I just wanted to get in the habit of using help() as my first stop for finding information about something in Python (unless there are convincing arguments that this is a bad habit to get into), and there must still be some gaps in my understanding of either help() and/or the Python object hierarchy if I cannot get this to work.

Thank-you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried

```
help(re.match) #help on method
```

or

```
 help(re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+)", "Isaac Newton, physicist")) #help on result
```

And official docs do look confusing. It does not seem that *MatchObject* class explicitly exists in Python.